# Unable to reference array when I am able to do so earlier

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, server

I am working on creating an online game, using node.js for the server. I have certain player names I want to assign to users when they login. The player names are loaded from a JSON file and I am able to log the player names when they are loaded however when I log the players when a user logs in it says undefined. My code is below.

```js
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var fs = require("fs");

var playersRequired = 3;
var playersHad = 0;
var playerNames = [];
var players =[];
var gameStart = false;
var gameRunning = false;

class Player {...}

fs.readFile(__dirname+"/Gamedata/characters.json",function(err,data){
  console.log("Loading Characters");
  playerNames = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(playerNames);
  for(var i = 0; i<Object.keys(playerNames).length;i++){
    console.log(i);
    players[i] = new Player(playerNames[i].name,playerNames[i].description);
    //this works and logs the players:
    console.log("yet another player "+players[i].name+"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
  }
  //console.log('Creating player objects: '+JSON.stringify(players,0,2))
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("listening");
});

console.log('starting');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('get / request');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('disconnect',function(){
    console.log('a player disconnected');
    playersHad--;
    if(playersHad <0){
      playersHad = 0;
    }
  });
  socket.on('login',function(data){
    console.log("Player logged in");
    playersHad++;
    console.log(playersHad+" players have logged in");
    //this does not work and returns undefined:
    console.log("This user is: " + players[playersHad]);
    socket.emit("Name",players[playersHad]);
    if(playersHad == playersRequired){
      if(!gameRunning){
        gameRunninng = true;
        game();
      }
    }
  });
  socket.on('disconnect',function(){
    players--;
  });
});

function game(){...}
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't look like it's relevant to the problem you are describing?

Comment: The code to load the players is in the middle of it. Should I delete what is not that relevant?

Comment: I think you have an scope problem!

Comment: Sorry, looks like you edited your code after I looked at it.

Comment: @funcoding that is what I thought it was, though I could not find where it was of figure out how to fix it

Comment: i think we need to see your json file. At the moment it looks as though you're trying to access object properties via an incremental index

Comment: @hairmot I don't think that that is the problem because I can read it and create the player objects. The problem is that I can't read it later. Here is the format of a player in the JSON file:                                                               "number here":{
    "name":"name here",
    "description":"description here"
  },

Comment: Did you typed it here or did you have it like this in your code
`console.log("This user is: " + players[playersHad);` You are missing something :)

Comment: I just typed it like that here. I have the square bracket in my code. I just fixed it!

Comment: This would happen pretty easily if `characters.json` took a long time to load, since you are not waiting for it to load before `server.listen()` or any of the other logic. It is preferable to nest the callbacks in an appropriate order to avoid [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). You will then want to refactor the callbacks into named functions so that you can "un-nest" them visually. Or even better, use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: Did you try logging `players` array inside `login` event. Does it contain anything?

Comment: @TarasDanyliuk when I log players in the login event it is null

Comment: exactly `null` or `undefined` or `[]`?

Comment: @TarasDanyliuk when I log players in the login event it is says null, when I log an element of players in the login event it says undefined

Comment: Something wrong in your logs, because you can't get this without error `null[1]`, and your logs says that you can

Comment: can you create a fiddle with all your code in this file and post it here?

Comment: @TarasDanyliuk to run this you need to run the app.js file above using node.js in a command line

Comment: I can try to help if you provide me with your code somehow

Comment: @TarasDanyliuk ok working on it

Comment: @TarasDanyliuk do you know how I can send the files to you?

Comment: If you have repo you can email me link to it. Or just send files there
taras.danylyuk@coaxsoft.com

Comment: You better hurry up. I have only half an hour(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are off by 1. You are updating playersHad before logging from players. Players is 0 indexed, and you are keeping track of length with 1,2,3 etc.

Your code should be

```
socket.on('login',function(data){
 console.log("Player logged in");
 playersHad++;
 console.log(playersHad+" players have logged in");
 //this does not work and returns undefined:
 console.log("This user is: " + players[playersHad - 1]);
 socket.emit("Name",players[playersHad - 1]);
 if(playersHad == playersRequired){
   if(!gameRunning){
     gameRunninng = true;
     game();
   }
 }
});
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: This does not work. For some reason I still get undefined.

Comment: While there seem to be other things going on, the off by 1 error should be handled like in the snippet I provided. @seth above mentions that you could have a race condition. Try using fs.readFileSync to avoid this.